# error for insert and stored data in access 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, insert, ms-access-2013

i have this code for insert data into access 2013
after click in the save button data insert into dataGridView and show

and when stop program and restart this,data not stored in the DB.I've done a lot of searches but can't find the solution. my class code and my button save code

```
class DB
{
    public static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    static DB()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                "Data Source=|DataDirectory|//Phonebook-db.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
    }
    public static void Insert(Person p1)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            con.Open();
            string s = "INSERT INTO Industrialist (S_Name,S_Family,S_Telephone,S_Major)VALUES('" + p1.Name + "','" + p1.Family + "','" + p1.Telephone + "','" + p1.Major + "')";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = s;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Record successfully Added");
        }
        catch (OleDbException exp) { MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString()); }
    }
```

}

```
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = txtname.Text;
        p.Family = txtfamily.Text;
        p.Telephone = txttell.Text;
        p.Major = txtmajor.Text;
        DB.Insert(p);
        txttell.Text = "";
        txtmajor.Text = "";
        txtname.Text = "";
        txtfamily.Text = "";
        List<Person> people = DB.GetPeople();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = people;
```

Comment: Is there any exception? or what problem you are facing?

Comment: no exception.this code work , but data just show in grid and not stored in the DB

Comment: Do you get the success message "Record successfully Added"?

Comment: yes,i get this message

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting some type of connection closed exception since the connection is being closed before `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: yes,im sorry,I wrote the code wrong,but me have same problem ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose your ACCDB file listed in your project files, select `Copy To Output Directory` and set its value to `Never` (And remember that |DataDirectory| is a substitution strings that points (for ASP.NET projects) to APP_DATA, your record is inserted in the database copied in that directory.

Said that please consider to use a parameterized query to create an sql command, not string concatenations

```
   try
   {
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();
        string s = "INSERT INTO Industrialist (S_Name,S_Family,S_Telephone,S_Major)VALUES(" +
                   "?,?,?,?)";
        cmd.CommandText = s;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",p.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",p.Family);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",p.Telephone);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4",p.Major);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Record successfully Added");
    }
    catch (OleDbException exp) { MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString()); }
```

Of course do not close the connection before executing the command.

Another point to change is the usage pattern of your connection. Do not create a global connection and keep it around for the lifetime of your application. Simply create and use it when needed and close/dispose immediately after

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                      "Data Source=|DataDirectory|//Phonebook-db.accdb;" + 
                      "Persist Security Info=True"))
{
   try
   {
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        ....
   }
} // <- Here at the closing brace the connectio will be close and disposed
```

Comment: one question,, what are diffrent between parameterized query and not string concatenations?

Comment: Well, suppose that p.Name contains a name with a single quote inside, like `H'atami` (just for example of course). Then when you build the string and pass to the db engine the command will fail with a syntax error (the single quote ends the value part and the remaining text is not valid sql). Worst, search for `sql injection`

Comment: Glad for you. seeing you as a first time user, could I suggest you to look at FAQs or to the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about)